# Why can't PyInstaller find the exe file that it is supposed to be creating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I am currently using `PyInstaller` to create a standalone program (for windows) in order to make it easier for less technical users to use. I have a spec file that has worked in the past, but is suddenly no longer working. `PyInstaller` returns an error saying

> WARNING: stderr: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'H:\Projects\My_Project_Dir\dist\app.exe'

It seems strange that the only issue it seems to have is with one of the files it is supposed to be creating, but I'm not sure what could be causing it.

The only dependencies are related to `Kivy`. I followed their guide here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

`PyInstaller` does seem to recognize `Kivy` and use the hooks.

I did add another Tree statement to the COLLECT function, which was "Tree('SDL2-2.0.10-win32-x64')", in order to pull in the SDL dll file.

Unfortunately, I am under restrictions about sharing the code itself, as this is a work project. If no one has any ideas, I will see what I can share.

Edit:
I can share the spec file, with the app name removed:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew


a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['H:\\Projects\\My_Project_Dir'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,

             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('./'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               Tree('SDL2-2.0.10-win32-x64'),
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='app')
```

Comment: << I did add another Tree statement to the COLLECT function, which was "Tree('SDL2-2.0.10-win32-x64')", in order to pull in the SDL dll file. >> Could you explain why you did that? Thanks!